# How can I dynamically build a linq OR query where one of several columns can match the search string?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

How can I dynamically build a linq `OR` query where one of several columns can match the search string? This is not that hard to do in SQL. For example:

```
SELECT     ID, Title, Description, Comments, CreatedBy, CreatedOn, UpdatedBy, UpdatedOn
FROM         Category
WHERE     (Title LIKE '%Supplier%') 
    OR (Description LIKE  '%Supplier%')
```

Sometimes I will need to add `OR (Comments LIKE  '%Supplier%')` or omit `OR (Title LIKE  '%Supplier%')` and that is why I want to build it dynamically.

I do not believe this is a duplicate question because the potential duplicate is not asked in a way that it can be found using the Stackoverflow search function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this with a combination of ideas from evanmcdonnal and dasblinkenlight.  I gave each of them an upvote since unfortunately, I could not give them each credit for having helped answer the question. This is what I ended up writing.

```
private static IQueryable<Db.Category> FilterContains(string searchFor, string excludedBrFields, IQueryable<Db.Category> categories)
{
    if (searchFor.StartsWith("*") && searchFor.EndsWith("*"))
    {
        searchFor = searchFor.Substring(1, searchFor.Length - 2);
    }
    searchFor = searchFor.ToLower();

    var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Db.Category>();
    if (!excludedBrFields.Contains("Title"))
    {
        predicate = predicate.Or(x => x.Title.ToLower().Contains(searchFor));
    }

    if (!excludedBrFields.Contains("Description"))
    {
        predicate = predicate.Or(x => x.Description != null && x.Description.ToLower().Contains(searchFor));
    }

    if (!excludedBrFields.Contains("Comments"))
    {
        predicate = predicate.Or(x => x.Comments != null && x.Comments.ToLower().Contains(searchFor));
    }
    return categories.Where(predicate.Compile()).AsQueryable();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You just use the or operator like you would elsewhere in C#. The code snippet below should basically do what you want. The string literals could instead be local variables.

```
 MyObjects.Where(x => x.Someprop == "my string" || x.SomeOtherprop == "my string").Select(...)
```

For your example you would actually want something more like

```
 Where(x => x.Comments.Contains("Supplier") || x.Description.Contains("Supplier"))
```

Note that those SQL wild cards equivalent C# methods will be; Contains, StartsWith, and EndsWith. You could also use RegEx to match more sophisticated patterns.

Comment: We are definitely on the right track. However, sometimes I will need to add "OR (Comments LIKE '%Supplier%')" or remove "OR (Title LIKE '%Supplier%')" and that is why I want to build it dynamically. I won't know which columns to query until runtime. How do I handle those cases?

Comment: @Tarzan you have some different options there but I would recommend just writing different versions of the query and determining which one gets run with a typical if-elseif structure. The other option that comes to mind is to use reflection but that is more work than it's worth imo.

Comment: I ended up solving it with a combination of ideas from you and from dasblinkenlight.

Answer (score 2):

Building a query with `OR` *dynamically* is not as straightforward as it is to build a query with an `AND`. If you are set on building the query dynamically, you can use the [*Predicate Builder*](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx). If you do not mind having a single query that can ignore parts of its condition dynamically, you can use the query below:

```
bool checkTitle = ...
bool checkDescription = ...
string likeString = ...
var res = context.Category
    .Where(item =>
        (checkTitle && item.Title.Contains(likeString))
        ||
        (checkDescription && item.Description.Contains(likeString))
    );
```

Since `str.Contains("xyz")` translates to `str LIKE '%xyz%'`, this query would correspond to a SQL query like this:

```
SELECT ID, Title, Description, Comments, CreatedBy, CreatedOn, UpdatedBy, UpdatedOn
FROM   Category
WHERE  (@checkTitle=1 AND Title LIKE '%Supplier%') 
    OR (@checkDescription=1 AND Description LIKE  '%Supplier%')
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Lambda. Might work for you.

```
context.Category.Where(x=>x.Title.Contains("Supplier") || x.Description.Contains("Supplier")).Select(x=>new {....});
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is LINQ example:

```
public IEnumerable<Items> FindBySupplier(string supplier)
{
return context.Items.Where(i => i.Title.ToLower().Contains(supplier.ToLower()) || i.Description.ToLower().Contains(supplier.ToLower());
```

}

Comment: You call to lower then pass Contains a string that starts with an uppercase letter... That code will never work.

Comment: Yeah, sry, I meant Supplier is a variable, not hardcoded string.

Comment: that still doesn't work. If you're doing string comparisons and apply to lower or to upper to one of the strings you must apply it to the other your logic is unsound.

Comment: This example works in my program

Comment: Depending on the data source you are querying...the query may be case insensitive.  MySQL would be one example of this